# How do you make a list comprised of a unit and number into just a list with numbers?

Tags: python, list

I have a `list = ["154 cm", "123cm", "145cm"]`

How can I change the list into `["154", "123", "145"]`?

I used `split()`, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
a = ["154 cm", "123cm", "145cm"]
res = re.findall('\d+', ' '.join(a))
print(res) #['154', '123', '145']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> a = ["154 cm", "123cm", "145cm"]
>>> [i.replace("cm", "").strip() for i in a]
['154', '123', '145']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.match` on each of the elements in your list to match digits (`\d+`) at the start of the string:

```
import re
l =  ["154 cm", "123cm", "145cm"]
out = [re.match(r'\d+', v).group() for v in l]
```

Output:

```
['154', '123', '145']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by replacing the white space and `"cm"` with empty strings like this:

```
raw_data = ["154 cm", "123cm", "145cm"]
data = [_.replace(" ", "").replace("cm", "") for _ in raw_data]
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a regular expression. For example:

```
import re

l = ["154 cm", "123cm", "145cm"]

print([re.sub(r"\s*(\d+).*", r"\1", s) for s in l])
```

gives:

```
['154', '123', '145']
```

This will match the whole string, consisting of possible whitespace followed by one or more digits followed by anything else, and replace it just the digits.

(Limitation: it is assumed here that the elements of the input list do all match the expression, as any that do not will appear unmodified in the output.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from itertools import repeat

def remove_unit(data, unit):
    lst = list(map(str.partition, data, repeat(unit)))
    return [item[0].strip() for item in lst]

data = ["154 cm", "123cm", "145cm"]
print(remove_unit(data, 'cm'))
```